stop ScrollController from affecting a ScrollController below it - Flutter
i have the following list (buildtask lists is basicly a normal listview):
Expanded(

               child: buildTaskList(
                  context: context,
                  scrollController: _listScrollController, // Pass this controller to the list
                  title: 'Done Tasks',
                  tasks: doneTasks,
                  dynamicShadowOffset: dynamicShadowOffset,
                  stickyHeaderHeight: stickyHeaderHeight,
                  bottomTaskItemMargin: bottomTaskItemMargin,
                  topTaskItemMargin: topTaskItemMargin,
                  stickyHeaderShadowHeight: stickyHeaderShadowHeight,
                ),
              ),

inside a sliding up panel (which has a different scroll controller):
return SlidingUpPanel(
      controller: _panelController,
      panelBuilder: (scrollController) => _panelContent(scrollController, context),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(16)),
      minHeight: 0.1 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      maxHeight: 0.5 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      isDraggable: _isDraggable,
      onPanelSlide: (position) {
        _panelPositionNotifier.value = position;
        if (widget.onPanelSlide != null) {
          widget.onPanelSlide!(position);
        }
      },
    );

The problem is that since the list is above the sliding up panel scrolling the list also scrolls the panel. how can i make scrolls performed on the list not effct the scroll controllers under it so the sliding up panel wont be affected by it?
please help me im desperate
was trying to put a list inside a sliding up panel so scrolling it wont affect the panel
it does not work, scrolls on the list are also applied to the sliding up panel
